# GitHub Error when starting Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github

VS 2015:

I get this error when I start VS:
[image: Error when VS starts]

Below is an entry in the log file. I don't have a Y: drive and I don't have any users or projects named "Jenkins".

```
  <entry>
    <record>98</record>
    <time>2017/03/13 21:27:54.615</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [GitHubPackage]Source: &apos;GitHub.VisualStudio&apos; Description: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at GitHub.VisualStudio.GitHubPackage.Initialize() in Y:\jenkins\workspace\GitHub for Visual Studio speakeasy jenkinskeep\src\GitHub.VisualStudio\GitHubPackage.cs:line 58&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{C3D3DC68-C977-411F-B3E8-03B0DCCF7DFC}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Comment: This happens when you start Visual Studio or when you open a project?

Comment: When I start VS. Every time.

Comment: Try running this command from an administrator visual studio command prompt `devenv /resetuserdata`